# How does terraform determine when to download modules?

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

I would like to use the EKS module of terraform.

```
module "eks" {
    source = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
    version = "17.22.0"
    ...
}
```

This is working fine.

What i want to achieve is that terraform does not download the module if it is already present locally. I am using the terraform variable `TF_DATA_DIR` to set the data directory for terraform.

```
export TF_DATA_DIR="${SOME_DIR}/.terraform"
```

When I am running `terraform init` the EKS module is still pulled from the registry, even when the module exists locally. When I run `terraform init` a second time this does not happen.

```
terraform init
terraform init
```

Ouput:

```
...
Initializing modules...
Downloading terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws 17.22.0 for eks.eks...
- eks.eks in .terraform/modules/eks.eks
- eks.eks.fargate in .terraform/modules/eks.eks/modules/fargate
- eks.eks.node_groups in .terraform/modules/eks.eks/modules/node_groups
...
Initializing modules...
...
```

The files are always loaded into `"${SOME_DIR}/.terraform"` so I expect the `TF_DATA_DIR` to work as expected.

How can I prevent terraform to download modules when they are already present? I don't want to use a local path, I would like to use the caching mechanism.

I am using Terraform version 0.14.7

Comment: You can pin the version of the module: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/sources.html#terraform-registry. In short, just add `version = x.x.x` in the module section. Otherwise it will always download the latest version.

Comment: @MarkoE it's not about that, I am already pinning it, just omitted it here for the sake of simplicity. The files in my `"${SOME_DIR}/.terraform"` have the same content before and after the `terraform init`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

Since I've used the terraform variable `TF_DATA_DIR` with different values for each `terraform init` execution the content in `.terraform/modules/modules.json` was different and thus it has been re downloaded.